# SO no working - Certificate problem?

Tags: bug, ssl

Anybody else experience this when going to stackoverflow.com?

[image]
[image]

Comment: what happens when you reload the window?

Comment: @SagarV a same thing

Comment: I think the certificate is for another domain. If it is the certificate of SO, it should show issued to *.stackexchange.com

Comment: try clearing cache and login or try to open so in an incognito window

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me.

Comment: Funny how this is exactly what https protects against, but nobody expects it to happen.  You are getting redirected, you'll have to find out why.  SO has been a popular target, I suspect if you allow it to connect then you'll see wonky ads in awkward places.  Lots of users have reported such browser injection attacks in the past.